# Parse a string as a command line input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing

I need a help on this string parsing.
What i want to do is to parse a string like this one using Javascript.

```
"myname" secondarg "third argument" andso on
```

to give me a result like

```
[0] => myname
[1] => secondarg
[2] => third argument
[3] => andso
[4] => on
```

EDIT:

```
"test" " foo" bar "hello world" " hello "
```

to

```
[0] => 'test'
[1] => ' foo'
[2] => 'bar'
[3] => 'hello world'
[4] => ' hello '
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function argsFrom(string) {
    return string.match(/'[^']*'|"[^"]*"|\S+/g) || [];
}
```

That is pretty decent, but it doesn't deal with escaped quotation marks, etc. It's pretty complicated to have a complete solution, just as complicated as parsing CSV.

[Javascript code to parse CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data)

Comment: how can i get rid of the extra leading and trailing double quotes on the output?

Comment: maybe, use string replacement later `.replace(/"/g,"")` for each element of array